# How can i define an object of arrays using attrs?

Tags: python, python-attrs

Consider the following data set:

```
{
    'name': 'somecat',
    'lives': [
        {'number': 1, 'did': 'nothing'},
        {'number': 2, 'did': 'saved the world'}
    ]
}
```

What I am trying to do is use `attrs` to define a dataclass so that I can get autocompletion even when using an index number

```
import attr

@attr.s
class Cat(object):
    name = attr.ib()
    lives: list = [
        {'number': int, 'did': str} # trying to get autocompletion here
    ]


c = Cat('somecat')
print(c)
c.lives[0].number # trying to get autocompletion here
```

The above code is not valid, but this is what I am trying to accomplish.

How can I go about doing this? I am aware of `metadata`, but that is immutable. I am open to using `dataclasses` also if that makes more sense.

Comment: You could make `lives` a list of `namedtuples` and I believe that will auto complete

Comment: Thanks @Buckeye14Guy. Would you happen to have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly I never really use the `attr` module but in order to make minimal changes to your code. I think using `typing.List` is also useful here. I personally would've used dataclasses but this seems to work as well

```py
import attr
import typing
from collections import namedtuple

live = namedtuple('live', ['number', 'did'])


@attr.s
class Cat(object):
    name = attr.ib()
    lives: typing.List[live] = attr.ib()


c = Cat('somecat', lives=[live(**{'number': 1, 'did': 'smile'})])
print(c)
c.lives[0].number  # auto completes
```

With just dataclasses

```py
import typing
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class live:
    number: int
    did: str


@dataclass
class Cat:
    name: str
    lives: typing.List[live]


c = Cat('somecat', lives=[live(**{'number': 1, 'did': 'smile'})])
print(c)
c.lives[0].number  # autocompletes
```

But for nested dictionaries, these dataclasses can be tough. Like so

```py
data = {
    'name': 'somecat',
    'lives': [
        {'number': 1, 'did': 'nothing'},
        {'number': 2, 'did': 'saved the world'}
    ]
}

new_c = Cat(**data)
new_c.lives = [live(**data) for data in new_c.lives]
```

If I may, I would suggest looking into [`pydantic`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/).

Thanks

Comment: Why would you mix `namedtuple` and `attrs`? Defining a  `Life` Class seems the obvious choice and you took it for DCs.

Comment: :) I stated that I wasn't too familiar with `attrs` and I gave my personal opinion on using dataclasses since I use them regularly.

Comment: I originally asked for attrs just to have backwards compatability amongst different py versions. I ended up going with the `pydantic` solution.

Comment: Nice. The `pydantic.Basemodel` class is very handy and it has worked for me on horribly nested data.

Comment: Yes, totally agree. `pydantic` is extra awesome specially because of its validation and the exception actually makes sense!